# when does "open a bounty" show up

Tags: support, bounties

i have some questions without accepted answers that are weeks old and "Open a bounty" doesn't show up.  What is the logic around if that option exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/):

> Users may only have one active question bounty at any given time.

Since you currently have an [open bounty on a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466514/how-do-i-set-the-correct-height-when-using-javascript-google-bar-chart), you can't add another one.

Comment: It would be a good idea to show the "Start bounty" link at all times, but greyed out (possibly with an explanation) when you can't open one yet. It goes against SO's general philosophy but would prevent confusion. Also, it would make people more aware of the possibility of bounties.

Comment: i agree with Pekka.  this is quite confusing (unless you knew upfront about this rule)